# I need to find a common architecture for wpf and web forms

Tags: wpf, mvvm, webforms

My shop is moving towards re-working the app to be a combination of WPF and web forms.
Some functionality will be facing the public via web forms and some will be internal only via WPF. I'm trying to find a common architecture for both sides of the equation.  From what I've seen so far MVVM is the best bet for the WPF side, but that doesn't seem to apply as well to web forms.

**Update:**

Thanks for the replies.

> "why can't you have two very different
>   architectures? Web Forms and Win Forms
>   or WPF and Silverlight."

Microsoft announced awhile back that there would be no new development in WinForms so it doesn't make any sense to go that route.

The reason for the common architecture (if possible) if so we don't have 2 different code bases/knowledge bases etc etc.

The app is very much LOB (line of business) with heavy use of grids and data entry forms etc etc. I know when WPF initially came on the scene there wasn't much in terms of data controls (such as no data grid) but WPF now has controls via Telerik (sp?) and others including Microsoft itself had been leaning toward webForms for same reason.

What's the status regarding Silverlight at this point in time?

Comment: Try to stay away from Web Forms... ASP.NET MVC 2 is out, and I'd pick it ANY DAY over Web Forms!!!

Answer (score 2):

There is [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/). Prism is designed to help you more easily build modular Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and Silverlight client applications. These types of applications typically feature multiple screens, rich, flexible user interaction and data visualization, and role-determined behavior. They are "built to last" and "built for change."

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [good design](http://layersample.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=LayerSample&DownloadId=129253](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=LayerSample&DownloadId=129253)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have picked to very different presentation platforms why can't you have two very different architectures? Web Forms and Win Forms or WPF and Silverlight.